# How to change the size of the system buffer in linux for uart?

Tags: c

Please tell me, I'm making a uart logger based on arabian linux on an orange pizero single-board computer, the following code turned out, but I can't beat the problem. I lose information if I transfer large text files, the order of several hundred bytes inside the text disappears. My assumptions are related to the overflow of the system buffer, but I could not figure out how to increase it using the ioctl() system call. The transfer rate is 921600.

My code-

```
struct termios2 SerialPortSettings;

ioctl(fd_uart,TCGETS2,&SerialPortSettings); 

SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;    //Remove current baud rate
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= BOTHER;    //Allow custom baud rate using int input
SerialPortSettings.c_ispeed = 921600;    //Set the input baud rate
SerialPortSettings.c_ospeed = 921600;    //Set the output baud rate
//tcgetattr(fd_uart, &SerialPortSettings); /* Get the current attributes of the Serial port */
/* Setting the Baud rate */
// cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,921600); /* Set Read  Speed as 921600                       */
// cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,921600); /* Set Write Speed as 921600                       

/* 8N1 Mode */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    //Disables the Parity Enable bit(PARENB),So No Parity   
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   /* CSTOPB = 2 Stop bits,here it is cleared so 1 Stop bit */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;    /* Clears the mask for setting the data size             */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;      /* Set the data bits = 8                                 */


SerialPortSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       /* No Hardware flow Control                         */
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; /* Enable receiver,Ignore Modem Control lines       */ 

SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          /* Disable XON/XOFF flow control both i/p and o/p */
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG | ECHOE| IGNCR);  /* Non Cannonical mode                            */

//SerialPortSettings.c_lflag = 0;
SerialPortSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;/*No Output Processing*/

// ioctl(fd_uart, TIOCINQ, 8000);

// ioctl(fd_uart, TIOCOUTQ, 8000);

// serial_struct serinfo;
// memset(&serinfo, 0, sizeof(serinfo));
// ioctl(device_handler, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo);
// serinfo.xmit_fifo_size;

// /* Setting Time outs */
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN] =  0;
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;


// serial_struct serinfo;
// memset(&serinfo, 0, sizeof(serinfo));
// ioctl(device_handler, TIOCGSERIAL, &serinfo);
// serinfo.xmit_fifo_size;

tcflush(fd_uart, TCIOFLUSH);   /* Discards old data in the rx buffer*/

//tcsetattr(fd_uart, TCSANOW, &SerialPortSettings);
if((ioctl(fd_uart, TCSETS2, &SerialPortSettings)) != 0) /* Set the attributes to the termios structure*/
    printf("\n  ERROR ! in Setting attributes\n");
else{
    printf("  BaudRate = 921600 \n  StopBits = 1 \n  Parity   = none \n");
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might not solve your problem with a larger buffer, unless it can contain the entire file. But double-buffering might help.

Comment: How to make it? I need to increase the system buffer in linux, allocating more memory in c via malloc does not solve anything.

Comment: Your assumption could be wrong, there could be a simple bug in the code that either sends the data, or in your code that receives the data. (Even if you observe that it works with smaller text or non-arabic text, it could be a bug in the reading side, or issues with charsets etc. (Make sure you're sending a character encoding that your code properly handles )

Comment: I will send the data via western, just a text file with LF at the end of each line, I read the data in c and write them to the file descriptor via read() write() linux system calls, there are no problems at lower speeds, the uart lines are short, there are definitely no connection problems either. The whole problem is in the correct configuration of the uart in linux(

Comment: Note that you are _not_ asking why your program does not work, or how to make it work, or even not asking if there is a flaw in your understanding. You are _specifically_ only asking how to increase the buffer size of UART driver. Which is a XY question and most probably is not what you really want - you want to implement reading from the file descriptor in a separate thread with buffering (i.e. double buffering). The real problem lies in the "_how_" are you reading the data, most probably, your program is too slow. It could also be, that the platform has just not enough CPU power.

Comment: The task is to write two log files from two uart ports of the device. In my case, I use orange pi zero + cp2102 converters. The built-in uart on the orange pi zero board does not work at a speed of 921600, so such a crutch in the form of a usb-uart adapter. Arabian distribution (based on Debian), kernel version 5.10.60-sunxi. CP210X or usbserial driver modules

Comment: I do not exclude that I am wrong in part of the code, so I can show it if someone has time to point out my mistakes to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Non Cannonical mode

In non-cannonical mode, the buffer is fixed at 4096 characters. This is following the documentation, see `man termios` and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L1583 . The kernel setting is like here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/tty.h#L247 .

> How to change the size of the system buffer in linux for uart?

Recompile the kernel with bigger value of the buffer.

Comment: +1.  It's also worth repeating the comments above: 1) [The OP's] assumption could be wrong.  2) [The OP] is *specifically* only asking how to increase the buffer size of UART driver. Which is a XY question and most probably is not what [he] really wants -  to implement reading from the file descriptor in a separate thread with buffering (i.e. double buffering). The real problem lies in the "how" are he's reading the data, most probably, the program is too slow. It could also be, that the platform has just not enough CPU power.

Comment: No, the code is as simple as possible, I can throw it somewhere, there are 370 lines in one file without headers. I think the mistake is that I don't understand how to properly configure the uart so that it can handle the speed of 921600. Well, the process takes 10% of the computing power, and the board has 4 cores of 1200mhz frequency. Is she really not able to write to a file so fast?