# Python - Data loss while listening 2 different serial ports on 2 different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, python-multithreading

I am trying to listen 2 different serial ports ("dev/ttyUSB0" and "dev/ttyUSB1") at the same time in parallel. What I am trying to do is simply listening both ports and if new data arrive to one of the ports, enqueue that data to a queue. In main method, I am continuously listening to the queue if there exists anything new or not. If so, I dequeue it and proceed with other steps. Also, while proceeding with other steps, I also want to keep listening to my serial ports as well.

Here is what I have implemented for this:

```
data_queue = []

def serial1():
    while True:
        data_1 = ser1.read_serial()
        data_queue.append([data_1, "1"])


def serial2():
    while True:
        data_2 = ser2.read_serial()
        data_queue.append([data_2, "2"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f_thread = threading.Thread(target=serial1)
    f2_thread = threading.Thread(target=serial2)

    f_thread.start()
    f2_thread.start()

    # I have also tried to join them like below.
    # But since my main method has to be running and listening to the queue all the time,
    # joining them did not work.
    # f_thread.join()
    # f2_thread.join()

    while True:
        if data_queue:
            print("*****New data has arrived.*****")
            new_data = data_queue.pop(0) 
            print(new_data)
            if new_data[1] == "1":
                pass # proceeding with other steps
            elif new_data[1] == "2":
                pass # proceeding with other steps
            else:
                print("smth wrong")
```

Problem is, while both threads are running, I can not take the all data from serial (it arrives with a huge loss; 45000 character long string arrives as 7-8k character long). However, when I close one of the threads and work with only 1 thread, I can take the full data from serial:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f_thread = threading.Thread(target=serial1)
    f_thread.start()
```

What is the reason behind that and what would be the solution? Any help is appreciated, thank you so much in advance.

I've tried to join the threads but it did not work. I've tried to use async functions but since I am not too familiar with them, I could not make it working properly as well.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a `Lock` to synchronise access to `data_queue`. (btw you don't show how that is created)

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for your answer and sorry for the missing code, it is actually an empty list but I have added it to the top. For your suggestion about Lock, I don't believe the problem causes by the access to data_queue. Why did you think so?

Comment: Well, when you restrict the program to one thread, the situation improves. Programming is not about belief, its about what a computer can actually do. Did you try a `Lock`?

Comment: (Also, you don't need to call `.join()` until the program wants to exit).

Comment: @quamrana Believe was not the correct word :). I did try a lock to synchronise the access to the queue. Nothing changed, the data keep arriving with a huge loss.

Comment: Actually I think you should be using multiprocessing instead of multithreading. -> you arent actually communication bounded. but processing bounded. Your global lock would prevent the complete transfer of long messages. In your single thread example there is no competing thread hence no issue.

Comment: Ok, so using a `Lock` can be tricky. Perhaps a `queue.Queue()` might be better.

Comment: PySerial does not have a method called `read_serial()`. The source code you provided seems incomplete. Please describe the exact package you're using, or provide the complete source code that you would have written, including the `read_serial()` method. [How to create ... Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Or if `read_serial()` is just another name for `read()`, why not read the size of the data in the buffer at once instead of reading one byte at a time? [in_waiting](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting)

Comment: If the data is lost even if you specify the read size, it seems that the default device driver buffer is 4KB in linux, so why not change the OS or device driver, rebuild it, and modify PySerial to support it? [How to change the size of the system buffer in linux for uart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71599589/9014308) It seems that such customization is done in Windows. [Setting buffer size in windows #337](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/337)